# Interractive plots Ipython 5.0.0 in the terminal

Tags: linux, matplotlib, terminal, ipython

I run Ipthon in the terminal, in linux (**not** a jupyter notebook).

In Ipython 2.4.1, the following commands opens a pop up interactive `Tk`
plot window:

```
(prodEnv)[kv@loowkv1 sandbox]$ ipython
IPython 2.4.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.


In [1]: 

In [1]: %matplotlib
Using matplotlib backend: TkAgg
In [2]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
In [3]: import numpy as np
In [4]: plt.ion()
In [5]: x = np.arange(0, 4*np.pi, 0.1)
In [6]: y = [np.sin(i) for i in x]
In [7]: plt.plot(x, y, 'g-', linewidth=1.5, markersize=4)
Out[7]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f5c8a8b6410>]
```

In Ipython 5.0.0, when I use the same code:

```
(prodEnv)[kv@loowkv1 sandbox]$ ipython3
Python 3.4.1 (default, Nov  3 2014, 14:38:10) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.0.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: %matplotlib
   ...: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   ...: import numpy as np
   ...: plt.ion()
   ...: x = np.arange(0, 4*np.pi, 0.1)
   ...: y = [np.sin(i) for i in x]
   ...: plt.plot(x, y, 'g-', linewidth=1.5, markersize=4)
   ...: 
Using matplotlib backend: agg
Out[1]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7fe49ae9c208>]
```

nothing appears. How do I get my poping up interractive plot in Iptyhon 5.0.0?

Comment: `%matplotlib` takes an additional optional parameter for the backend you want to use. See `%matplotlib --list` for a list of all available backends

Comment: Ok, which one should I choose to get the same plots as in ipython 2.4.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your output with `ipython` using `TkAgg` i.e. tk (python-tk) as backend.

> Using matplotlib backend: TkAgg

But with `ipython3`, it is `agg`

> Using matplotlib backend: agg

I try with `ipython3` and `TkAgg` backend it's working just fine as `ipython`.
You may need to install `python3-tk` to use `TkAgg` with `matplotlib`

Comment: yes, I was hoping for a way to do this without using the sudo command (from the virtual env), but it seems impossible.